# ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

I have:

```
data1=open('file1.txt','r')
data2=open('file2.txt','w+')

for line in data1.readlines():
    items = line.split(' ')
    x = log(float(items[0]))
    y = float(items[1])
    data2.write(x)
    data2.write('\t')
    data2.write(y)
    data2.write('\n')
```

where file1 contains

```
l   0.1
2   0.1
3   0.1
4   0.1
5   0.1
6   0.1
7   0.1
8   0.1
9   0.1
10  0.1
```

Getting

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 1
```

I dont quite understand why im getting an error, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the full Error message?

Comment: Is there a **l** in the first line of the file or is it a typo?

Comment: At least post the correct traceback: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: l`

Comment: full error message

 x = log(float(items[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the first line of your file is letter `l` which cannot be converted to a float number. Maybe it is a typo and you want it to be number `1`? if so, then your code will be correct. Then you need other changes in order to make your code more pythonic like using `with` for dealing with files:

```
from math import log
txt = list()
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fr, open('file2.txt', "w+") as fw:
    for line in fr:
        items = line.split()
        txt.append("{0}\t{1}".format(items[0], log(float(items[1]))))
    fw.write("\n".join(txt))
```

Comment: And OP should use `line.split()` not `line.split(' ')`, otherwise they'll get the same error again but this time for an empty string.

Comment: OP is clearly not applying `log` to each item in `items` and why `file.readlines`?

Comment: `for line in fr:` is much better.

Comment: You are welcome,  remember that the best way to say thanks in SO is by upvoting/accepting an answer :)

Comment: sorry, i looked over at it again, and i think i still need some help.

what if i wanted to log the first column and leave the second column as it is?

such that:
log(float(items[0])),items[1]

Comment: Then change the line to `txt.append("{0}\t{1}".format( log(float(items[0])), items[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

What jabaldonedo said, + `split(' ')` splits most of your lines into a list of several items, not just 2, because each line contains multiple spaces not just one.

For example:

```
>>> '2   0.1'.split(' ')
['2', '', '', '0.1']
```

so `items[1]` will definitely not give you what you need.

A quick solution would be to simply take the last element of `items` by doing `items[-1]`. But best do the splitting properly (i.e. using regular expressions):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(' +', '2   0.1'.split(' '))
['2', '0.1']
```

Or, if you'd rather not use regular expressions, another slightly inelegante workaround would be:

```
>>> items = '2   0.1'.split(' ')
>>> items = [x for x in items if x]
>>> items
['2', '0.1']
```

**NOTE:** I'm using interactive Python, in case you were wondering about the `>>>` prefixes.

**UPDATE:** `'2   0.1'.split()` (i.e. `split()` without argument) seems to do exactly the same job; i.e. it gets rid of the multiple spaces, so to say. (thanks, @hcwhsa).

Comment: just `'2   0.1'.split()` is enough.

Comment: seems you're right—`split("2     0.1")` gives `['2', '0.1']`... didn't know that; not intuitive at all :)